# How to Detect and Identify German Compound Words in a Text using Python

Tags: nlp, data-mining, data-science-model, ai, llm

I would like to know if there is any python libraries or packages available which can help me detect and extract German compound words. I took a look at nltk and spacy packages and they don't seem to have such libraries. I have given a sample paragraph that contains some compound words and then I listed those compound words.

PS: compound words are made of two or more nouns, verbs, adjectives, or adverbs.

"Das Fahrradfahren ist eine beliebte Freizeitaktivität in Deutschland. Viele Menschen fahren gerne mit dem Fahrrad zur Arbeit oder nutzen es für lange Radtouren durch die malerische Landschaft. Einige bevorzugen sogar das Mountainbiking oder das Rennradfahren, um das Adrenalin zu spüren. Andere wiederum schätzen das E-Bikefahren für eine entspannte Fahrt ohne große Anstrengung."

Fahrradfahren
Freizeitaktivität
Radtouren
Mountainbiking
Rennradfahren
E-Bikefahren

Comment: Have you looked at [this github repository](https://github.com/repodiac/german_compound_splitter) or [one](https://pypi.org/project/german-nouns/) of [these](https://pypi.org/project/compound-split/) python packages?

Comment: @Oxbowerce Yeah I have experimented with a few packages and finally used compound_split package which was built by University of Zurich.